# Consuming a WCF Service From Another Project

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am performing the following steps.

1. Created a WCF service using WCF Service Library
2. Run and Test the WCF service by pressing F5 in the project (and it runs fine)
3. Create another project in the same solution in Visual Studio
4. Add Service Reference to the WCF Service I created earlier in Step 1

However, the new project does not recognize the WCF Service I created in Step 1. How can I consume a WCF Service created in a different project?
The same service call works fine when it’s called from the same project. I get a red line on using HelloWorld2;

```
  using HelloWorld2; 

namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // Helloworld2 client = new Helloworld2();

        // Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.
       // Name person = new Name();
       // person.First = "Adam";
       // person.Last = "Smith";

       // Response.Write(person.First);


    }
}
```

}

Comment: How does it not recognize it? Are there compiler errors?

Comment: Did you add the required using statements? Adding just the reference won't help.

Comment: Geethanga, when I try the "using" statement, it does not recognize the namespace and gives me an error

Comment: Lews, the service works and compiles fine, when I add a new project and add reference to the Service that works fine too. But when I attempt to call the service it gives me error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I was missing the code where you add references

ServiceReference2.Helloworld2Client cc = new ServiceReference2.Helloworld2Client();
            ServiceReference2.Name person = new ServiceReference2.Name();

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if a service is called from the same project or not.

Could you check Fiddler and see what HTTP traffic is being sent?

Comment: Andrew, the Service compiles ok. When I try Adding Service Reference from a different project that works fine too. But when I attempt to call the service in the code, it fails to recognize the service. I have added code in the original question.

Comment: It doesn't compile when you attempt to call the service or it blows up at runtime?

Comment: It gives me a red line under using HelloWorld2; and does not recognize the reference

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Helloworld2 client = new Helloworld2();

Comment: You may need to right click on the project and add a reference to your other project in visual studio.

Comment: Yes, I have done that already as explained in Step 4 of my question

Comment: So you have a "Web References" folder in the project you're trying to call this service from?

Comment: Yes I can see a "References" folder. Thanks for the hint. Am I missing anything here? Do I need to make Reference to any of the files here?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure what the problem is then. Sorry I can't help